# Front page changes from "answered" to "modified"

Tags: bug

I answered a [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/105694/28015) last night, then the OP accepted a different answer which was edited by Ray Mairlot 12 hours ago at the time of this question.

After I answered, I looked at the main page again and noticed `answered by JakeD...` next to the question as usual. However, this morning I looked at the main feed and saw `modified 11 hours ago JakeD` for this question, but I never edited any answer or the question.

[image]

Comment: did you edit your answer in the 5 min grace period?

Comment: @David No, I did not...I didn't know that existed for answers and questions, but I didn't make any edits.

Comment: This error has been reported on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259531/278094) already.